# localNotification performe action at firedate

Tags: ios, notifications, action, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to run -(void)doaction from the Appdelegate when the firedate is equal, but it only show the initWithTitle, and the cancelButtonTitle it doesn't do the whole action and it crash then i tap the cancelButton, I don't know why plz help. Here is what I have tried.

Viewcontroller.m

```
 NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                startDate:&pickerDate
                                 interval:NULL
                                  forDate:pickerDate];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];


if (localNotification) {


    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

 }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}
```

the action.

```
- (void)doaction{

if (!recorder.recording){
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
    [player setDelegate:self];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"name" message:self.wakeMessage.text delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [player play];

    [alert show];


}
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
 if (buttonIndex==0) {
    [player stop];
}
```

And in the Appdeleget.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification(UILocalNotification *)localNotification { 
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc doaction];
}
```

thanks in advance